# How do I move my swap file to another disk?

Tags: release-freya, swap

When I installed doth HDDs were recognised but elementary only gave the option to put things on one. I chose my SSD. It insisted on putting the swap file there too. Can I get access to the other drive now and move my swapfile? How do I do that?

Comment: Consider that most modern installations don't require a swap partition.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to access the drives when they're not mounted, so install `gparted` on [a "live CD" or thumb drive](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), where you'll be able to toss your swap on one disk and create one on another.

Now to [activate the partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

1. Boot up elementary OS again and run `sudo gparted`. Right-click on the swap drive and go to "Properties".
2. Copy the partition's UUID.
3. Run `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and look at the line with "swap" in its third column. Replace the old UUID with the new one, save, and exit.
4. Enable the swap with `sudo swapon --all --verbose`
5. Confirm its existence with `cat /proc/swaps`
6. `reboot` to make sure it loads

Comment: You don't need to use a Live CD here. You might only run `sudo swapoff -a`, fire up `gparted` and create a new swap partiton and continue by step 2.

Answer (score -1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

This should basically have all the information you'll need.

Basically make a swap partition(or file) on the second drive and then configure swapon to use it.